# Reverse Words in a String , I do not know why I am getting this output

Tags: c++

```
class Solution {
public:
    string reverseWords(string s) {
        int n=s.size();
        
        string p;
        vector<string> arr;
        
        
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            p=p+s[i];
            if (to_string(s[i]) == " "){
                arr.push_back(p);
                p = "";
            }
            if (i==n-1){
                arr.push_back(p);
                break;
            }
        }
        string q;
        int m=arr.size();
        for (int j=m-1;j>=0;j--){
            q=q+arr[j];
        }
        
        return q;
        
    }
};
```

```
Wrong Answer
Runtime: 0 ms
Your input
"the sky is blue"
Output
"the sky is blue"
Expected
"blue is sky the"
```

Comment: Side note: you should add a `' '` to the last word of the input string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::to_string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is a function which converts *a number* to `std::string`. Since no number can ever be represented as `" "` (a string containing a single space), your condition is never true.

Change your condition to

```
if (s[i] == ' ')
```

to compare *characters*.